# lxml raises a TypeError on using a simple custom parser

Tags: python, xml-parsing, lxml

I have written the following simple parser (to showcase the problem in my slightly more complicated program) which extracts the titles from all of the entries in the [DBLP xml database](http://dblp.uni-trier.de/xml/).

```
from lxml import etree

class DBLPTarget(object):
    def __init__(self, outfile):
        self.inField = False
        self.outfile = outfile

    def start(self, tag, attrib):
        if tag == 'title':
            self.inField = True

    def end(self, tag):
        if self.inField and tag == 'title':
            self.inField = False            

    def data(self, data):
        if self.inField:
            self.outfile.write('%s\n' % data)

    def close(self):
        pass

outfile = open('dblp-selected.txt', 'w')
parser = etree.XMLParser(target = DBLPTarget(outfile), load_dtd=True)
infile = 'dblp.xml'
results = etree.parse(infile, parser)
outfile.close()

print("Done.")
```

Upon running this code on the dblp.xml file, it chugs along for a while (generating about 72K of content) and then raises the following error message.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/je24621/Desktop/dblp-example2.py", line 30, in <module>
    results = etree.parse(infile, parser)
  File "lxml.etree.pyx", line 3197, in lxml.etree.parse (src\lxml\lxml.etree.c:65042)
  File "parser.pxi", line 1571, in lxml.etree._parseDocument (src\lxml\lxml.etree.c:93101)
  File "parser.pxi", line 1600, in lxml.etree._parseDocumentFromURL (src\lxml\lxml.etree.c:93388)
  File "parser.pxi", line 1500, in lxml.etree._parseDocFromFile (src\lxml\lxml.etree.c:92445)
  File "parser.pxi", line 1047, in lxml.etree._BaseParser._parseDocFromFile (src\lxml\lxml.etree.c:89329)
  File "parsertarget.pxi", line 160, in lxml.etree._TargetParserContext._handleParseResultDoc (src\lxml\lxml.etree.c:100233)
  File "parsertarget.pxi", line 154, in lxml.etree._TargetParserContext._handleParseResultDoc (src\lxml\lxml.etree.c:100143)
  File "lxml.etree.pyx", line 294, in lxml.etree._ExceptionContext._raise_if_stored (src\lxml\lxml.etree.c:9383)
TypeError: function takes exactly 5 arguments (1 given)
```

For reference, I'm doing this on Windows 7 (not by choice) with Python 3.2.5 and lxml 3.2.1. How do I fix/debug this?

Comment: What version of `libxml2` do you have? (If there's a bug in the library, rather than in your code, it turns out to be in `libxml2` more often than in `lxml` itself.)

Comment: Also… when I download the dtd and xml.gz files (and gunzip the xml.gz) and run this, it fails immediately because the DTD is invalid. (You're not allowed to have a comment before the `<?xml?>` declaration.) Are you running with the exact same files that are on that site?

Comment: And meanwhile, if I remove the `load_dtd=True`, everything completes successfully, with a 3.8M-line output file, after a few seconds (although it does screw up the non-default `&uuml;` entities that are defined in the DTD).

Comment: I am running it on exactly the same dtd file as found on the website. I will try removing the comment.

Comment: Same error, but I have never experienced a problem with invalid DTD... how do I check my version of libxml2?

Comment: on removing load_dtd=True I still get the same error.

Comment: The easiest way to find your `libxml2` version is to look at the header file `…/libxml2/libxml/xmlversion.h`. Right near the top, there will be a line like `#define LIBXML_DOTTED_VERSION "2.7.8"`. If you've installed a binary `lxml` that doesn't include the `libxml2` headers, it should say on whatever site you got the binary from.

Comment: By the way, this kind of error is a huge pain to debug. There are various places during parsing where the parser can store an exception for later (see `store_raised` calls in [the source](https://github.com/lxml/lxml/blob/master/src/lxml/parser.pxi)); if they do so, on closing, the exception is raised by `raise_if_stored`. The traceback may be available in the re-raised exception, but unless you have Python 3.3+ you probably won't see if, so you have to wrap a `try`/`except` and dig it apart manually. And that still only tells you so much about what failed.

Comment: no clue where this is on my Windows machine... :( got I hate windows.

Comment: Well, you have to find it, or remember how you installed it.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what the actual problem you're seeing is. I tried with lxml 3.2.1 and Python 3.3.1 with both today's snapshot of libxml2 and the 2.7.8 version supplied by Apple, and in both cases, it immediately fails because the DTD is invalid.

Just removing the `load_dtd=True` makes the whole thing work, with 3.8M lines of output. It obviously doesn't understand the custom elements and entities specified in the DTD properly. You don't depend on those elements, but the entities are a problem. For example, instead of replacing `&auml;` with `ä`, you get a replacement character.

So, there seem to be four ways to deal with this:

1. Figure out how to make the `lxml` happy with your DTD.
2. Find a different parser that works with the broken DTD.
3. Embed the DTD into the XML file (as in [this example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Type_Definition#XML_DTD_schema_example)).
4. Don't use the DTD, and instead pre-parse the data. Since the only thing you actually need is the custom entities, you can do this by simply replacing each entity with its definition. Of course you won't get validation this way… but you're failing validation anyway.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone interested, this issue was not resolved, and it just appears there is a bug somewhere in the library. Instead, I parsed the xml by hand using regular expressions.